# How can I restore the executable bit of /bin/chmod?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have removed the executable permission from `/bin/chmod`

How can I recover from this scenario?

Comment: Here are several answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-chmod-without-usr-bin-chmod

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods. The easiest will probably be:

```
install -m a+x /bin/chmod .
./chmod
```

[image]

---

You can use perl. see `man 2 chmod`.

```
perl -e 'chmod 0755, "/bin/chmod"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution may be to boot using a live CD, mount the file system and change the permissions from there.